# jquery calculate the sum of columns then add to existing total

Tags: jquery

I have seen plenty of examples on here where the sum is calculated from the quantity and the price columns and a total is added up at the bottom of the table.

I am using this idea but want to take it further. In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/k8amK/1/) I have an additional colum called country and a seperate table down the bottom that lists the country and their yearly total. I want to be able to add a value to the quanty field and have it update both the sum and the yearly total. eg if I put in 1 in the FIN row the sum will be 2.45 and the yearly total will be 247.45.

I don't think I can hardcode a variable eg

```
var $fin= 245;
```

because the data in the second table will change as actual sales are made but this page is just for the user to do a quick projection so I am unsure on the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you get started

```
var countryValue = parseFloat($("#totalsTable td:contains('" + countryText + "')").next().text()) + sum;
$("#totalsTable td:contains('" + countryText + "')").next().text(countryValue);
```

'#totalsTable' is an ID added to your bottom table.

The use of the 'contains' and 'next' selectors may stop working if the table structure stays the same.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply here. I haven't had any luck in getting this working as you have described. I can't seem to get a different value in each row of my #totalsTable, is there any more advice you might be able to offer here please?